# No sound in Adobe Premiere Pro CC 2017

Tags: premiere

I'm importing .MP4 file which has music in it, but in Premiere there is no audio track at all.

I have restarted PC, installed K-lite codec pack, Quicktime codecs but why? Why is it so hard to simply import an .MP4 file with music to the video editor?

I searched the internet a lot but only find useless advice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, here is [answer](https://forums.adobe.com/message/9109650#9109650). 
Quote:

> Please clear the Media Cache (keeping Premiere Pro closed). Find
>   instructions here: FAQ: [How to clean media cache files?](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2152942)
>
> Navigate to the Media Cache location as specified in the Premiere Pro
>   preferences and rename the folders.
>
> ```
>    MAC: Premiere Pro menu>Preferences>Media
>    Windows: Edit Menu>Preferences>Media
> ```
>
> Please reply if your issue gets resolved after trying these steps.
>
> NOTE: Premiere Pro will conform all files after opening any/all
>   project(s) and will generate the peak file for the audio. This might
>   take long depending upon the number of Media used in the project(s).

Answer (score 0):

Hold Alt when starting Premiere. It will ask you if you want to reset your settings. Click yes.  This worked for me.

https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2126506

Answer (score -1):

[Telion's answer](https://video.stackexchange.com/a/20957/5657) was helpful to me in the past, but today it took me an hour to figure out that after some copying and pasting from other projects, my audio track had some Track Keyframes (notice the difference from Clip Keyframes) that were causing the volume to be 0.

So, I switched into the Track Keyframes mode and then used the Pen tool to highlight all of those keyframes, and I deleted them.

Answer (score -1):

I used to solo the tracks, and then the audio would play and that usually does the trick. This time, that didn't work. After several restarts and quitting Premiere, I gave up and duplicated my project. Now audio works!